# Return the selected text from a dropdown box

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to return the text from a dropdown box that is selected on an Excel form. I have tried many things and the closest I have gotten is returning the index number. Also had a look at:

Link: [Return the text from a dropdown box rather than the index number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078898/in-excel-vba-return-the-text-from-a-dropdown-box-rather-than-the-index-number)

I haven't found a working solution on that page. I have tried things such as:

```
ActiveSheet.DropDowns("DropDown1").Value
ActiveSheet.DropDowns("DropDown1").Text
ActiveSheet.DropDowns("DropDown1").SelectedValue
ActiveSheet.Shapes("DropDown1").Value
```

etc.

Comment: You state _"...dropdown box that is selected on an excel form."_ but the link and sample code refer to shapes on a sheet.  Which are you trying to do? Also, which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I'm using excel 2010. Hmm well in one part of my code I refer to the dropdown as ActiveSheet.Shapes and that part of code works fine. accessing it through dropdowns also works..

Comment: I am unsure what you are using: have you added a control to the sheet (eg from the Developer tab, Inset a Form or ActiveX control, and if so which one) or are you adding data validation to a cell or range (eg from Data tab, Data Validation, and if so exactly what is the setup)

Comment: Yeah I added it through the Form controls under Developer tab.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will return the current selection from the DropDown

```
Sub TestDropdown()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dd As DropDown

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set dd = ws.Shapes("DropDown1").OLEFormat.Object

    MsgBox dd.List(dd.ListIndex)
End Sub
```

BTW, assigning to a variable declared as `Dim dd As DropDown` will give you intellisense on `dd`

Comment: Wow it worked like a charm. I never would have figured that out, I thought it would have been something simple like .SelectedIndex. Thanks Chris.

Answer (score 7):

You can also get the caller name, if the macro is called by the dropdown box itself. This way you don´t have to worry about renaming the dropdown boxes :)

```
Sub Dropdown_OnSelect()
    Dim dd As DropDown

    Set dd = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).OLEFormat.Object

    MsgBox dd.List(dd.ListIndex)
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the real answer, since getting the object name is a PITA.

Answer (score 3):

If you are unable to `Dim as DropDown` I found that this alteration will work.

```
Sub TestDropdown()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dd As Object

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set dd = ws.DropDowns("DropDown1")

    MsgBox dd.List(dd.ListIndex)
End Sub
```