# How can I use a value from a dropdown list as a condition for an if statement in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a for loop that includes the following if statement:

```
...For x = 1 To lr:
       If Range("G" & 1) = "Complete" Then...
```

The problem is the string `"Complete"` is an option in a dropdown list from data validation in every cell in column G, and my if statement isn't recognizing it as true even if it's selected. How can I get it to recognize a value from a dropdown? Thanks!

Comment: Can you [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53326186/edit) to include the actual code? If it's `If Range("G" & counter) = "Complete" Then`, it isn't "coming from the dropdown list" at all.

Comment: Is the dropdown an ActiveX control? A Forms control? A data validation dropdown? How you'd get the dropdown's value differs very much depending on what type of control you're looking at. `Range("G" & counter)[.Value]` could be how you'd go about checking a cell's content, i.e. when the "dropdown" is merely an in-cell data validation dropdown.

Comment: Also, `counter` is going to be constant at every iteration of that loop. Did you mean to use `x`?

Comment: You need to set your listbox value as a variable. i.e. `Dim lbVal as long` `lbVal = Listbox1.Value`. So `For x = lbVal to lr`  `If Range("G" & x) = "Complete"` Change the "Listbox1' to the name of your listbox.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon It's an in-cell data validation. I was using a counter there for another purpose, but for the context of this question using x makes more sense so I updated it.

Comment: @Comintern I edited the question to hopefully make more sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return the selected text from a dropdown box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578038/return-the-selected-text-from-a-dropdown-box)