# Populate the selected value from a drop down box into a separate worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a form for work that is auto populated from a pre-existing customer form, but the drop  downs and I are disagreeing. Due to this form being for work and being used/transferred through multiple organizations, I do not want any drop down boxes. What I am looking at doing is to have the selected values from the drop down boxes auto populate into the corresponding cells within the new form. ie: The drop down is in OriginalSheet D12 and I want the selected value to populate in NewSheet D12.

I have tried all of these answers:

[Get dropdown value in VBA and get the name of the dropdown...nowhere to be found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826353/excel-2003-get-dropdown-value-in-vba-and-get-the-name-of-the-dropdown-no-where)
[Return the text from a dropdown box rather than the index number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078898/in-excel-vba-return-the-text-from-a-dropdown-box-rather-than-the-index-number)
[Return the selected text from a dropdown box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578038/vba-excel-return-the-selected-text-from-a-dropdown-box?lq=1)

and am currently on the below code, but I still cannot get the selected value to populate into the new cell:

```
Sub Dropdown()

Dim dd As Dropdown

Set dd = Sheets("LTL Quote Form").Dropdowns("Drop Down 63")
Set r = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D12")

Set ddValue = r(dd.ListIndex)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Dropdown()
    With ActiveSheet.DropDowns(Application.Caller)
        Sheets("Sheet3").[d12] = .List(.Value)
    End With
End Sub
```

Note: this assumes you have assigned the Dropdown() macro to the dropdown form control.

Note: this assumes that you want the value to appear in cell D12 of 'Sheet3'.